# When initiating a Pandas DataFrame, it automatically generates names of the columns like self.<column_name>; How?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I import a .csv file with columns [A, B, C] using `df = pandas.read_csv()`

Now I can access columns A, B, and C with `df.A`, `df.B`, `df.C`

However, defining object classes requires the variable to be predefined in their definition as in:

```
def Box:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 'ayy'
        self.B = 'bee'
        self.C = 'sea'
```

And they are accessed by calling `Box.A`, `Box.B`, `Box.C`

How do Pandas DataFrames make automatic generation of object attributes/properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas uses [__getattr__](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7a1dad130ce183a96f76f303120b688e998e129c/pandas/core/generic.py#L5148) to create this quick access to columns.

Accessing data via `df[..]` is implemented by `__getitem__`.